# 6502 Addressing mode with labels

Tags: assembly, label, 6502, addressing-mode

I'm looking at some code sample from this site:

http://www.6502asm.com/

And looking at it i see they have some instructions that instead of using the memory location directly they use a label, for example, in the alive.asm:

```
lda ypos,x
```

And ypos is

```
ypos:
dcb $00,$02,$20,$02,$40,$02,$60,$02
dcb $80,$02,$a0,$02,$c0,$02,$e0,$02
dcb $00,$03,$20,$03,$40,$03,$60,$03
dcb $80,$03,$a0,$03,$c0,$03,$e0,$03
dcb $00,$04,$20,$04,$40,$04,$60,$04
dcb $80,$04,$a0,$04,$c0,$04,$e0,$04
dcb $00,$05,$20,$05,$40,$05,$60,$05
dcb $80,$05,$a0,$05,$c0,$05,$e0,$05
```

I know that labels differs depending on the assembler, but i am assuming it is going through that list, but how it specificity works

Comment: The machine instruction loads a byte into A, from the address `ypos+X`.  It's a register + immediate displacement addressing mode.  It doesn't modify `X`, you'd have to do that separately.

Comment: Does my answer suit you ? If yes, please accept it, otherwise please indicate what is missing.

Answer (score 6):

Here are details about the instruction `lda ypos,x`:

1. If `ypos` is located out of zero page (equal to or more than 0x0100):

   - Opcode is 0xBD: it uses an ***indexed absolute*** addressing mode using the index register X, also called ***absolute,X*** mode
   - it computes an address by adding the content of X register to the 2-bytes address represented by the label `ypos`, then it loads the A register (accumulator) with the byte located at the computed address
   - its size is **3 bytes**; it takes **4 CPU cycles** + 1 cycle if page boundary is crossed, i.e. if the high byte of `ypos` is different from the high byte of the compute address `ypos + X`.
   - it updates only the status **flags N and Z** (Negative and Zero)
2. If `ypos` is located inside zero page (between 0x00 and 0xFF), then it may depend on your assembler (check the opcode): either it uses the ***indexed absolute*** addressing mode and it works as previously described, or:

   - Opcode is 0xB5: it uses an ***indexed zero-page*** addressing mode using the index register X, also called ***zeropage,X*** mode
   - it computes an address by adding the content of X register to the 1-byte address represented by the label `ypos`, **wrapping within the range 0x00-0xFF**, then it loads the A register (accumulator) with the byte located at the computed address.
     *Note: Be very careful, because it is probably not the expected behavior if the values defined at `ypos` go beyond the zero page. There might be a specific syntax in your assembler to force the absolute,X addressing mode.*
   - its size is **2 bytes**; it takes **4 CPU cycles**
   - it updates only the status **flags N and Z** (Negative and Zero)

Comment: "if the values defined at ypos go beyond the zero page..." you have more problems than the fact that the address wraps. Your data may get clobbered by the stack.